# Windows XP Automatic Updates keeps asking for reboot

Tags: windows, reboot, automatic-update

I installed updates via Automatic Updates (I have it set to "Notify but let me choose which to install"). Then I rebooted as prompted. Immediately upon logging in I received the message "You must restart your computer for the updates to take effect." So I did.

Now it continues to give me this message every time I log in, **even though no new updates have been installed.** Any ideas on how to make it realize that no reboot is needed?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution. Here's what I did:

1. Deleted `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update\RebootRequired`
2. Deleted `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\FileRenameOperations`
3. Did a Registry search on `HKLM\SYSTEM` and deleted every `PendingFileRenameOperations` value found.
4. Restarted the Automatic Updates service.

Apparently there had been corruption in a few of the values, indicating a reboot was required even though it wasn't. Completed those steps and voilà! Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

You can try taking a look at this [article](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/05/xp-automatic-update-nagging.html).

---

Try to disable Windows Update, restart ur system then re-enable.

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes 3rd party security software can cause this, perform a [clean boot](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/331796) Once the system restarts and cleanly boots, reverse the settings you changed in msconfig and reboot again, hopefully the message will be gone.

How to configure the system for a Clean Boot

> Step 1: Start the System Configuration Utility
>   Click Start, type msconfig in the Start Search box, and then press ENTER.
>
> If you are prompted for an administrator password or for a confirmation, type the password, or provide confirmation.
>
> Step 2: Configure Selective Startup options
>
> In the System Configuration Utility dialog box, click Selective Startup on the General tab.
>
> Click to clear the Load Startup Items check box.
>
> Click the Services tab.
>
> Click to select the Hide All Microsoft Services check box.
>
> Click Disable All, and then click OK.
>
> When you are prompted, click Restart.

.

If you do not get it sorted out contact Microsoft via [Free email support for Windows Update](https://support.microsoft.com/oas/default.aspx?LN=en-us&gprid=6527&x=18&y=11&st=1&wfxredirect=1&sd=gn).

Comment: Contact MS using the link I posted.